# Affinization of $T^*\mathbb{C}P^n$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, resolution-of-singularities, geometric-invariant-theory

Is there an elementary description of the affinization of the algebraic cotangent bundle of $\mathbb CP^n$? I know that it can be described as some sort coadjoint orbits, but I am interested in a translation of that to concrete equations. Is it correct that the cotangent bundle can be obtained from the affinization by a blowup at a point? If the general equations are too complicated, I would be interested in some low dimensional examples such as $n=2,3\dotsc$.

Answer (score 2):

Probably matrices of rank 1 with fixed trace gives the answer.

The condition rank not more than 1 is given by algebraic equations on minors.

The condition trace = C - will delete zero and nilpotent from this set.

Any such matrix M= column*row,
the map M-> row, gives the "projection" to P^n.

E.g. in 2x2 it is very simple we get condition det(M)=0, Tr(M)=1.
Tr(M) = 1 can be resolved explicitly taking matrix of the form [a b; c 1-a]
and we get equation a-a^2-bc = 0 - quadratic equation,
can be rewritten as  (a-1/2)^2+bc=1/4 - so we recognize hyperboloid which is known
 to be affine version of T^*P^1.

PS

This corresponds to coadjoint orbit description - rank = 1 Trace = C - is clearly a coadjoint orbit.

PSPS

Never checked the details but I think this is should be true

Comment: Alexander -- I think this works but you have to consider projections (i.e. maps $f$ such that $f\circ f=Id$), not just any linear maps; the trace than will automatically be 1.

Comment: this is not the "affinization", this is the smoothing. the affinization is given by taking things of trace=0 and rank at most 1 and T^*CP^n will be given by blowing up at the 0-matrix.

Comment: @algori Rank 1, trace 1 forces $f^2=f$ (which is what you meant). 

Comment: David -- yes, of course, for rank 1 linear maps the trace is 1 iff the map is idempotent. Daniel -- I interpreted "affinization" as "an affine variety isomorphic to"; if this is not what is meant here, then please disregard my remark.

Comment: David -- oh dear, I've just realized I'd written $f\circ f=Id$ instead of $f\circ f=f$, which is indeed what I meant. Sorry about the confusion. By the way, $f\circ f=Id$ would do as well, but then there will be a condition on the number of eigenvalues 1, not on the trace.

Comment: Affinization usually means Spec(\Gamma(O_X))...

Comment: David's description of the affinization $V$ is correct, but, if $n>1$,  the resolution $T^*\mathbb P^n$ is not given by blowing up the $0$-matrix (the unique singular point $P$ of $V$). The reason is that such a blow-up would introduce an exceptional divisor (something of codimension $1$) over $P$, whereas the exceptional locus has codimension $n$, by construction.

Comment: Oops! Thank you for pointing that out! I had the example n=1 in my head and made a big mistake by extrapolating

Answer (score 2):

The punctured cotangent bundle (excluding the zero section) of the complex projective space of dimension $n$ can be identified with the space:

$$\{(P,Q) \mid P^2=P, tr(P)=1, PQ+QP = Q, \operatorname{tr}(Q) = 0, Q\ne 0\},$$

where $P$ and $Q$ are $(n+1)$ dimensional Hermitian matrices.
Please see Furutani and  Tanaka's article [A Kähler structure on the punctured cotangent bundle of complex and quaternion projective spaces and its application to a geometric quantization I](https://doi.org/10.1215/kjm/1250518882) (Proposition 2.3.).

Sketch of the proof: The space of the matrices $P$ is isomorphic as a
homogeneous space to $CP^n$, since the action of $U(n+1)$ on it is
transitive and the isotropy group of any point is $U(n)$. The conditions
on the matrix $Q$ are obtained by taking the derivatives of the conditions
on $P$, and the identification of $T^*CP^n$ and $TCP^n$ via the
Fubini–Study metric.